# How to join two json path query in json path extractor of jmeter?

Tags: json, jmeter, jsonpath

Let's say I have this popular data sample.

```
{
    "store": {
        "book": [
            {
                "category": "reference",
                "author": "Nigel Rees",
                "title": "Sayings of the Century",
                "price": 8.95
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
                "color": "red", 
                "title": "Sword of Honour",
                "price": 12.99
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Herman Melville",
                "color": "blue", 
                "title": "Moby Dick",
                "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
                "price": 8.99
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
                "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
                "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
                "price": 22.99
            }
        ],
        "bicycle": {
            "color": "red",
            "price": 19.95
        }
    },
    "expensive": 10
}
```

What I want from here is a all the `book` where `category == fiction` and all the `bicycle` where `color == red`.

That is, I want,

```
   {
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
        "color": "red", 
        "title": "Sword of Honour",
        "price": 12.99
    },
    {
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Herman Melville",
        "color": "blue", 
        "title": "Moby Dick",
        "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
        "price": 8.99
    },
    {
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
        "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
        "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
        "price": 22.99
    },
    "bicycle": {
         "color": "red",
         "price": 19.95
    }
```

I know, I can use `$.store.book[?(@.category == "fiction")]` to achieve the targeted books and `$.store.bicycle[?(@.color == 'red')]` to achieve the targeted bicycle.

But how can I achieve both at one go?

Comment: This is a good question (independent of jmeter)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `&&` and `||` operators.

`$.store.*[?(@.color== 'red' || @.category == 'fiction')]`

will fetch the results as you wanted

Comment: I had that solution, But the thing it will search for `color` attribute and `category` attribute in both `cars` and `bicycles` and also match if `color` of  a `car` is `red`, but it is not desired. Hence I want to explicit check if `color` of `bicycle` is `red` or the `category` is fiction.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend implementing your scenario using [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and [Groovy language](http://groovy-lang.org/). Example code to extract the elements and build a new JSON out of the filtered data will look something like:

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(prev.getResponseDataAsString())

def fictionBooks = json.store.book.findAll {it.category == "fiction"}
def redBikes = json.store.bicycle.findAll{it.color="red"}

JsonBuilder builder = new JsonBuilder(fictionBooks + redBikes)

prev.setResponseData(builder.toPrettyString())
```

The above code will replace the parent sampler response data with the filtered JSON

[image: JMeter Groovy JSON]

References:

- [Groovy: Parsing and Producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [JsonBuilder class reference](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html)
- [Groovy Is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Answer (score 0):

To return books and bicycle, both you need to :

```
$..*[?(@.color== 'red' || @.category == 'fiction')]
```

For books which have color==red or category==fiction, you will need :

```
$.store.*[?(@.color== 'red' || @.category == 'fiction')]
```